# Auto update database of app in android

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, auto-update

I wrote app with offline database. But I want manually or automatically upgrade database sometimes. So can I upload my database in one of the upload centers in web and download it from app?
if yes, how?
any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show data present on your server then use ***REST*** web service API and try to have data in the form of ***xml or json*** (I prefer json). Parse the grabbed data and render it. There are many key features which need consideration so, research thoroughly.I think this [article](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/05/android-update-application.html) is worth of reading.

try this [article.](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)
i think this what you looking for.To sync data present in remote MySQL DB to Android SQLite database. The data present in the remote MySQL DB (or any Database) needs to be synced with SQLite DB in Android in order to maintain the data integrity.
If there is change in remote DB data, it can be synced with Android SQLite DB when User explicitly hits ‘Sync’ button or asynchronously by the application itself (in particular interval) when Internet connectivity is available.
[image]

Comment: Tnx but I said , I don't want use webservice and json, Is it possible to upload my database some where and then download it from my app? Is yes how? If no what the easy and best way for update data from app?

Comment: Than you can create a remote database than use sqlite for your app and update your remote database when you want and let sqlite to synchronize with your remote database. And check time to time and auto update, like for a one week period ans so. i edit my answer just check that too.

Comment: thank you , How it is possible. I don't know what can I do and whats the codes.

Comment: Dude i think you didn't read the [article](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/) i guess. it contain all the required code and a tutorial video to do it.

Comment: thank you I read that article, But as I said I have no host , website or server so I can't use JSON. I want to upload my db file some where for example "rapidshare" and download by my app and the update database . Is this possible?? if yes how?

Comment: some one please help me it's very necessary for me.